# Applying custom filters for aggregation in Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have more that 2 million documents which has price and discount. I have to get percentage of products with 10%, 20%, 30%,......, 90%, 100% discount(discounts are rounded off). Its not possible to fetch data and aggregate it on application layer at it will take too much time. I am also afraid that it will create lag for other users as thread will be busy for a long time.

Is there any way I can create custom filters upon aggregation logic?

Comment: These are two completely unrelated questions. Could you split them into two posts?

Comment: @imotov Removed second part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you need a custom filter here. This functionality is a standard part of the [histogram aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-aggregations-bucket-histogram-aggregation.html). You can also take a look at the [range aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-aggregations-bucket-range-aggregation.html) in case you need more flexible ranges.

If you need a complete flexibility in how terms are calculated you can also use [script in terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation-script) to return the value you want to group your records by. However, with 2 million documents, it might be better to pre-calculate the discount during before indexing the document, store this value as a separate field and then use histogram aggregation.

Comment: I went through histogram API. But I could not find any way to do computations on keys from document. For percentage I need to operate on price and discount keys.